# failed to set upstream: discovery eureka is uninitialized

Tags: netflix-eureka, api-gateway, discovery, apache-apisix

I am trying to connect apisix with the eureka discovery service. But I am getting this error.

```
error [error] 49#49: *913 [lua] init.lua:551: handle_upstream(): failed to set upstream: discovery eureka is uninitialized, client: 112.134.1.155, server: _, request: "GET /api/v1/decodeToken HTTP/1.1", host: "52.53.116.106:9080"
```

The configured **config.yaml** file is as follows:

```
apisix:
  node_listen: 9080              # APISIX listening port
  enable_ipv6: false

  enable_control: true
  control:
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    port: 9092
  discovery:                       # service discovery center
      eureka:
        host:                        # it's possible to define multiple eureka hosts addresses of the same eureka cluster.
          - "http://52.53.116.106:9072" # Access address of Eureka Server started by Spring Boot
        prefix: "/eureka/"
        fetch_interval: 30           # default 30s
        weight: 100                  # default weight for node
        timeout:
          connect: 2000              # default 2000ms
          send: 2000                 # default 2000ms
          read: 5000                 # default 5000ms
```